# Change columns of paragraph form table

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

If you have a paragraph reference field on a node you'll see a form table on node creation or node edit. Is there a way to change the columns of that table? Now you see:

- The type of paragraph
- The fields that are filled in
- Edit button

I want to delete the "type of paragraph" column and add some columns that shows what's filled in in the paragraph form.

Comment: If you delete the type of paragraph how does an editor know what it is later? My editors use it as a 'quick look' at the content hierarchy by scanning that column.

Comment: Yes I get that, but for our purpose we need to reformat that table with information which is more suitable for our content managers